# Different result in parsing datetime via calendsr or simpleDateFormatter

Tags: java, date, parsing, datetime, calendar

I now working with java 1.6 and encounter strange behaviour, may be bug, here is code:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class TestDate {
@Test
public void testConvert() throws Exception {
    Calendar parsedCalendar = DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime("0001-01-01T00:00:00");
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    Date sdfDate = simpleDateFormat.parse("0001-01-01T00:00:00");

    Calendar parsedCalendar2 = DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime("1980-03-01T00:00:00");
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    Date sdfDate2 = simpleDateFormat2.parse("1980-03-01T00:00:00");


    System.out.println("parsedCalendar: " + parsedCalendar.getTimeInMillis());
    System.out.println("parsedCalendar TZ: " + parsedCalendar.getTimeZone());
    System.out.println("parsedCalendar Date: " + parsedCalendar.getTime());
    System.out.println("sdfDate: " + sdfDate);
    System.out.println("sdfDate millis: " + sdfDate.getTime());

    System.out.println("parsedCalendar2: " + parsedCalendar2.getTimeInMillis());
    System.out.println("parsedCalendar2 TZ: " + parsedCalendar2.getTimeZone());
    System.out.println("parsedCalendar2 Date: " + parsedCalendar2.getTime());
    System.out.println("sdfDate2: " + sdfDate2);
    System.out.println("sdfDate2 millis: " + sdfDate2.getTime());

}
}
```

And here is problem:
[image: debug]

OUTPUT:

```
parsedCalendar: -62135622000000
parsedCalendar TZ: sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Novosibirsk",offset=25200000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=67,lastRule=null]
parsedCalendar Date: Mon Jan 03 00:00:00 NOVT 1
sdfDate: Sat Jan 01 00:00:00 NOVT 1
sdfDate millis: -62135794800000

parsedCalendar2: 320691600000
parsedCalendar2 TZ: sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Novosibirsk",offset=25200000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=67,lastRule=null]
parsedCalendar2 Date: Sat Mar 01 00:00:00 NOVT 1980
sdfDate2: Sat Mar 01 00:00:00 NOVT 1980
sdfDate2 millis: 320691600000
```

DEBUG:

```
 parsedCalendar.getTimeInMillis() = -62135622000000
    sdfDate.getTime() = -62135794800000
    parsedCalendar.getTime() = {Date@790} "Mon Jan 03 00:00:00 NOVT 1"
    sdfDate = {Date@759} "Sat Jan 01 00:00:00 NOVT 1"
    parsedCalendar2.getTimeInMillis() = 320691600000
    sdfDate2.getTime() = 320691600000
    parsedCalendar2.getTimeZone() = {ZoneInfo@755} "sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Novosibirsk",offset=25200000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=67,lastRule=null]"
    parsedCalendar.getTimeZone() = {ZoneInfo@756} "sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Novosibirsk",offset=25200000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=67,lastRule=null]"
    simpleDateFormat.getTimeZone() = {ZoneInfo@757} "sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Novosibirsk",offset=25200000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=67,lastRule=null]"
    simpleDateFormat2.getTimeZone() = {ZoneInfo@758} "sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Novosibirsk",offset=25200000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=67,lastRule=null]"
```

As you can see in parsing 0001 dateTime there is difference in ms! And in parsing 1980 it is not. 
Who can explain why?

Comment: I strongly *suspect* that `DatatypeConverter` is assuming a time zone of UTC if there's no offset in the string, whereas `SimpleDateFormat` will default to the system default time zone. I suggest you look at `parsedCalendar.getTimeZone()`.

Comment: If problem in TZ diffirence will be in both cases. I added second case with same parameters exactly to show that.

Comment: "If problem in TZ diffirence will be in both cases." Nope - if the system default time zone has a UTC offset of 0 at 1980-03-01T00:00:00 but a non-zero offset at 0001-01-01T00:00:00 you'd see *exactly* the behavior you've described. Instead of arguing that I must be wrong, why not just look at `parsedCalendar.getTimeZone()` as I suggested?

Comment: (It would also help if you'd tell us the system default time zone you're observing this with, so we can reproduce the issue.)

Comment: It is same timezone ofcourse i check it, to reproduce it use this code as is, in any your local TZ you will see difference between first pair and no between last, because everything in local TZ.
And this differnce in milliseconds its not hours its days. We dont have TZ difference in DAYS.

Comment: "It is same timezone" - same time zone as what? Yes, the two calendars will have the same time zone as each other, but what time zone is that? Of course, if you'd provided *text* instead of a picture, it would have been easier for us to work out the difference. (You didn't point out that the difference is very large - you just said "there is difference in ms".) I now suspect that this may be about the Julian/Gregorian cutover, possibly *as well* as time zones, but while you're reluctant to make it easy to help you, I'm not going to bend over backwards to do so...

Comment: I provide full working example of code, which anyone could copy paste and run/change/check every part you need. Its faster and easier way to everyone. Then ask and copy paste additional information one by one.

Comment: looks like gregorian cutover is the case.
However difference in gregorian/julian calendar is about 11 days and in parsing case it is about 3 days.

Comment: a) it's not complete. A complete example would include class declaration, imports etc so we could *just* copy/paste/compile/run. b) It's much better if an example produces text output which is shown as text in the question. Why force users to type in the milliseconds values in order to see the difference between them? c) You *still* haven't told us what time zone you're in; you've assumed it's irrelevant. Why not provide information when it's requested? The output I get will quite possibly be different from the output you get.

Comment: I'll happily add an answer if you improve the question, but I *won't* provide an answer on the question in its current state. It's really easy for you to improve it - why not do so?

Comment: Here you go, is it enough now?

Comment: Significantly better, although I don't know why you've used a unit test rather than just a console app that anyone can copy/paste/compile/run *trivially* without any other dependencies. (And the only thing you're printing out is a constant - why not print out the parsed calendar's time zone ID, and the various millisecond values? Hint: we shouldn't need to use a debugger to help you.)

Comment: I'll include the [mcve] *I'd* have provided in the question when I write an answer.

Comment: "hy not print out the parsed calendar's time zone ID, and the various millisecond values? "
Emmm, i have add them too, which could be copypasted, what you mean?

Comment: I mean that they're *not* printed out in your code. If we copy/paste/run your code, all it prints out is "something". Instead, you should make your example print out all the relevant information, and then include the exact output of that program into your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the difference between the Julian and Gregorian calendar systems.

`SimpleDateFormat` uses the default calendar system, which I believe to be `GregorianCalendar` on both your system and mine. `GregorianCalendar` (despite its name) switches between the Gregorian calendar system and the Julian calendar system, based on the `gregorianChange` property. It assumes that any date provided after that cut-over is Gregorian, and any before it is Julian. The default cut-over is in 1582.

`DatatypeConverter` uses a pure proleptic Gregorian calendar instead, as that's what the [W3C XML Schema docs require](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/datatypes.diff-wd.html#theSevenPropertyModel).

That means if you parse a value *just before* the calendar switch, you'll see a large difference - and that difference will get smaller as you go further back in time, with a difference of 3 days every 400 years. (The three century-years which aren't divisible by 400, and so are leap years in the Julian calendar but not in the Gregorian calendar.)

If you set the calendar in the `SimpleDateFormat` to a `GregorianCalendar` which you've called `setGregorianChange(Long.MIN_VALUE)` on first, the two will agree.

Here's code to make it easier to explore the difference:

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Test {    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        convert("0001-01-01T00:00:00");
        convert("1000-01-01T00:00:00");
        convert("1580-01-01T00:00:00");
        convert("1590-01-01T00:00:00");
        convert("1980-03-01T00:00:00");
    }

    private static void convert(String input) throws ParseException {
        Calendar datatypeConverterResult = DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime(input);
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
        Date sdfResult = simpleDateFormat.parse(input);

        System.out.println("Input: " + input);
        long datatypeConverterMillis = datatypeConverterResult.getTimeInMillis();
        long sdfResultMillis = sdfResult.getTime();
        long days = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(datatypeConverterMillis - sdfResultMillis);
        System.out.println("DatatypeConverter epoch millis: " + datatypeConverterMillis);
        System.out.println("SimpleDateTime epoch millis: " + sdfResultMillis);
        System.out.println("Difference in days: " + days);
        System.out.println("Parsed calendar time zone: " + datatypeConverterResult.getTimeZone().getID());
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Note that on Java 9, you need to specify the module explicitly. This is simplest done with java.se.ee:

```
$ javac Test.java --add-modules java.se.ee
$ java --add-modules java.se.ee Test
```

Output on my box:

```
Input: 0001-01-01T00:00:00
DatatypeConverter epoch millis: -62135596800000
SimpleDateTime epoch millis: -62135769600000
Difference in days: 2
Parsed calendar time zone: Europe/London

Input: 1000-01-01T00:00:00
DatatypeConverter epoch millis: -30610224000000
SimpleDateTime epoch millis: -30609792000000
Difference in days: -5
Parsed calendar time zone: Europe/London

Input: 1580-01-01T00:00:00
DatatypeConverter epoch millis: -12307248000000
SimpleDateTime epoch millis: -12306384000000
Difference in days: -10
Parsed calendar time zone: Europe/London

Input: 1590-01-01T00:00:00
DatatypeConverter epoch millis: -11991628800000
SimpleDateTime epoch millis: -11991628800000
Difference in days: 0
Parsed calendar time zone: Europe/London

Input: 1980-03-01T00:00:00
DatatypeConverter epoch millis: 320716800000
SimpleDateTime epoch millis: 320716800000
Difference in days: 0
Parsed calendar time zone: Europe/London
```

Comment: Hah, actually when i post my first question/example i have expected answer like your first or first and second paragraph only...